# amCharts 4 - How To Set Line Color Via Property Fields When No Data Added To Chart

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

Following [this demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-with-changing-color/), the following can be used to change the color of a LineSeries:

```
lineSeries.propertyFields.stroke = "lineColor";
lineSeries.propertyFields.fill = "lineColor";
```

This works if you add some data when making the chart.  But there are issues when no data is originally added.

See [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLrORY).  Errors occur.  Commenting out the `lineSeries.propertyFields.stroke` and `lineSeries.propertyFields.fill` lines allow data to be added to the chart via the "Add Data" button.

Is there a way to define the line color property field so that it works in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an issue on amCharts side, I will take a look at it. Meanwhile I would recommend setting property fields just before adding data for the first time.

Comment: This seems to work.  It should be noted that clearing the data later (e.g., via `chart.data = []`) also causes issues.  A workaround for this is to delete the `series.propertyFields.stroke` and `series.propertyFields.fill` properties (just setting the values to empty strings did not work) at the time the data is cleared (order did not seem to matter).  New data can then be added using same process of setting property fields immediately before using addData.

Comment: We fixed this issue in the latest release, you can set property fields now even if the chart doesn't have any data.

Comment: Confirmed working (without any workarounds). Thanks